# Can we perform outer product of set of two matrices simultaneously?

Tags: python, matlab

I want to perform outer product of two matrices of size say 3X25 so that I get a size 25X25. The question, I have say 2000 of such set of matrices, is there a way to perform all those simulataneously? I understand I can use a for loop for each set of two matrices but it is time consuming. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: This depends very much on your hardware and operating system.  What do you know about parallel processing and multi-threading?  That's generally how you perform things in parallel, but your speed-up will be constrained by your hardware: you can't perform almost 4 million simultaneous multiplications (three terms for each of 625 cells in each of 2000 matrices) if you have only 2 multiplication units.  Most contemporary CPUs (e.g. Intel Xeon) have 64x64 MATMUL as a machine instruction, but that simply lets you do each matrix as a whole: you still need to learn parallelism.

Comment: @Prune: What? Are you saying that there is a machine instruction that operates on two sets of 4096 floats in one go? I find that extremely hard to believe.

Comment: You are tagging Python and MATLAB at the same time. This makes the question extremely broad. Pick one language, please! You can always ask the question again for the other language.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: you're right.  The instruction is 16x16 floats; the pipelined example was 64x64.

Comment: @Prune: I found what you talk about [here](https://fuse.wikichip.org/news/3600/the-x86-advanced-matrix-extension-amx-brings-matrix-operations-to-debut-with-sapphire-rapids/). Very interesting! Unfortunately it only does 8-bit integer and 16-bit float (half precision) — it’s clearly aimed at Deep Learning. Also, it’s slated for release next year, if I understand correctly. Still, very cool addition to the CPU architecture.